# MySQL telling me credentials are incorrect when accessed through PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, database

I can access my database with

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and then by entering my password.

But when I try to login through a php script

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mypassword');
```

I get the following error

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /Library/WebServer/Documents/connect/index.php on line 6
```

When I run

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

in MySQL, I get the following (reformatted)

```
root@localhost | root@localhost
```

So I know the three parameters in my login function are correct, but I am not able to sign in.

I would appreciate any help.

Edit: Here are the grants

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*0503AA35367B049092549C66DFE0D6C3AA3C4970' WITH GRANT OPTION || GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

EDIT: just to be explicit, what solved my problem was using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is usually because of an incorrect username password combination.

User `root` normally has no password unless you've added one. Try going into PHPMYADMIN or other config files and dig up the password for `root`.

Another issuer is, you could try connecting to a specific database (the `fourth` parameter of `mysqli_connect` and do a `SHOW GRANTS` on user `root`) to ensure you have the privileges. `root` may not have the necessary grants, and I think that is what could be happening.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-grants.html

Edit: Answer in the comments, changed `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`, likly some configuration stuff in the server hosting environment

Comment: But I can log in successful using username root and my password that I've added.

Comment: Try adding in a valid `db_name` for the fourth parameter in `mysqli_connect` that `root` has grants on and tell me what happens.

Comment: Your password has the "@" symbol in it? I don't think that's the reason (despite the fact it is a PHP operator). Is your `localhost` not connecting correctly? You can try changing it to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. Why wouldn't just localhost work if I view the php file at http://localhost/...  ?

Comment: Are you running your server via. WAMP or XAMPP or some other environment?

Comment: Yes that's right - MAMP. Sorry if these questions are so elementary, I'm new to PHP/MySQL.

Comment: Hmm, to be perfectly honest, I'm not quite sure, it could be some weird configuration. I did a bit of research, but couldn't find any solid answers on the exact difference. I think MySQL on some environments or some server environments default to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/36460/mamp-not-working-as-localhost-but-works-with-127-0-0-1